# Pattern matching of character variables using SAS

Tags: sas

My dataset having character variable as "PANCARD" consist observations as:-
FGHIU9635F
DFGHI6953G
ZXCVB6325F
XCVBN9658G
DVHIGF963F
LPMJI44444
Now i want to extract a data from 10 thousand records using pattern matching using SAS. So that i will only get
FGHIU9635F
DFGHI6953G
ZXCVB6325F
XCVBN9658G
Conditions are:-
1) first 5 characters should be alphabets
2) next 4 charcters should be numeric
3) last one is alphabet.

Comment: This question (How do I do some stuff?) ist off-topic in SO. Please provide us some with some code. What have you tried so far? Where do you hang?

Answer (score -1):

Use perl Regular Expressions within SAS, is the most efficient way I have found. Here is a fine tutorial

[An Introduction to Perl Regular Expressions in SAS 9](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi31/110-31.pdf)

elaborating ...

```
     data match_values;
       input pancard $15.;

       /*------
         Parse pattern once while processing row 1 and not at every row
         ------*/
       retain p_1 p_2 p_3 p_all;
       if _n_=1 then 
       do;
         rule_pttrn_1 = "^[a-zA-Z]{5}";      /*first 5 characters should be alphabets*/
         rule_pttrn_2 = "^[a-zA-Z]{5}\d{4}"; /*first 5 alpha, next 4 charcters should be numeric */ 
         rule_pttrn_3 = ".*[a-zA-Z]$";       /* no matter what is at the begining, last one is alphabet*/

         /* parse all rules */
         p_1   = PRXPARSE("/" || rule_pttrn_1 || "/");
         p_2   = PRXPARSE("/" || rule_pttrn_2 || "/");
         p_3   = PRXPARSE("/" || rule_pttrn_3 || "/");
         p_all = prxparse("/^[a-zA-Z]{5}\d{4}.*[a-zA-Z]$/");
       end;

       /*-----
         test which patterns match 
         -----*/    
       match1   =prxmatch(p_1  ,strip(pancard));
       match2   =prxmatch(p_2  ,strip(pancard));
       match3   =prxmatch(p_3  ,strip(pancard));
       match_all=prxmatch(p_all,strip(pancard));

       /* keep only rows that match all rules */
       if match_all then output;
       keep pancard match:;

       cards;
       FGHIU9635F
       5DFGHI69530D
       $XCV66325F
       XCVBN96950R
       DVHITGF963
       LPMJI44444
       ;
    run;
```

Comment: @cpburnz Thanks for the comment, I'm new here just elaborated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
data have;
   input x $15.;
   if prxmatch('/^[a-z]{5}[0-9]{4}\w[a-z]{1}$/i',strip(x))>0 then output;
   cards;
   FGHIU9635F 
   5DFGHI69530D 
   $XCV66325F
   XCVBN96950R
   DVHITGF963
   LPMJI44444
   ;
run;
```